# Removing specific empty <p> from page

Tags: jquery

good Day

I am using wordpress and I have this annoying empty paragraph tag

below one of my div elements.

Now there are many other empty paragraphs on the page that I DO NOT want to remove, only this one..

Here is the HTML:

```
<div class="wpcol-one-quarter">
   <p><a rel="slb_group[803] slb slb_internal" href="http://asksomeone.co.za/wp-content/uploads/2013/03/boltmaster1.jpg"><img alt="boltmaster" src="http://asksomeone.co.za/wp-content/uploads/2013/03/boltmaster1-300x200.jpg" width="180" height="120" /></a></p>
</div>

<p>&nbsp;</p> <!--The culprit!!-->

<div class="wpcol-one-quarter">
   <p><a rel="slb_group[803] slb slb_internal" href="http://asksomeone.co.za/wp-content/uploads/2013/03/trackmaster.jpg"><img alt="trackmaster" src="http://asksomeone.co.za/wp-content/uploads/2013/03/trackmaster-300x200.jpg" width="180" height="120" /></a></p>
</div>
<div class="wpcol-one-quarter">
   <p><a rel="slb_group[803] slb slb_internal" href="http://asksomeone.co.za/wp-content/uploads/2013/03/multimaster.jpg"><img alt="multimaster" src="http://asksomeone.co.za/wp-content/uploads/2013/03/multimaster-300x200.jpg" width="180" height="120" /></a></p>
</div>
<div class="wpcol-one-quarter wpcol-last">
   <p><a rel="slb_group[803] slb slb_internal" href="http://asksomeone.co.za/wp-content/uploads/2013/03/facemaster1.4.jpg"><img alt="facemaster1.4" src="http://asksomeone.co.za/wp-content/uploads/2013/03/facemaster1.4-300x200.jpg" width="180" height="120" /></a></p>
</div><div class="wpcol-divider"></div>
```

Now I plan on removing it the following way:

```
            <script type="text/javascript">
                jQuery(function($){
                    var pathname = window.location.pathname;
                    if(pathname == '/803-2'){
                        $('div.wpcol-one-quarter').next(){

                            $('p').each(function() {
                                var $this = $(this);
                                if($this.html().replace(/\s|&nbsp;/g, '').length == 0)
                                    $this.remove();
                            });
                        }
                    }
                });
            </script>
```

**Why is it not working?**

thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
   jQuery(function($){

        var pathname = window.location.pathname;

        if(pathname == '/803-2'){               

                  $("div.wpcol-one-quarter").next('p:empty').remove();

                  if($("div.wpcol-one-quarter").next('p').html()=="&nbsp;") {
                   $("div.wpcol-one-quarter").next('p').remove();
                  }

        }
    });
```

Comment: can't you make it for an empty p tag?

Comment: I updated my answer, and here is a working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/7L4WZ/129/

Answer (score 2):

Try this :

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".wpcol-one-quarter").next("p:empty").remove();
});
</script>
```

Comment: Edited the answer please check it now

Comment: I will test it later and come back to you...thanks for your answer!

Comment: thanks, this works but not if the p tag contains a space : &nbsp;

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$('div.wpcol-one-quarter').next('p').filter(function () { return $.trim($(this).html()) == "" }).remove();
```

Comment: But this will remove all the empty p tags

Comment: nope does not work...for some reason only DextrousDave's answer work...but I'm looking for a more clean cut empty p tag remove solution

Comment: @DavidVanStaden : Check my anwser, I guess it will solve your issue

Answer (score 0):

It can't get any shorter, and you'll be sizing size on your js script code, which in the long run makes your stuff load faster.

```
$('p:contains("\xa0")').remove(); //to find all issues
```

or

```
$('.wpcol-one-quarter').next('p:contains("\xa0")').remove(); //to remove specific issue
```